# RAML same method overload documentation

Tags: rest, raml

I have 2 PUT methods in my rest API with the same entry point.

Method #1: PUT /videos/{videoId} with type multipart/form-data that will replace the video.

Method #2: PUT /videos/{videoId}?title=newTitle&description=newDescription that will update the video's title and description.

When I try to document it like following I get "method already declared: 'put'"

```
put:
  description: replace a video with a new video
  body:
    multipart/form-data:
      formParameters:
          file: 
            description: a video file to replace the current video file
            required: true
            type: file
  responses:
    200:
        body:
          application/json:
            schema: !include video.schema
            example: !include video.example
        description: Returns the video object.
put:
  description: update video's fields
  queryParameters:
    title:
      description: video's title
      required: false
      type: string
    description:
      description: video's description
      required: false
      type: string
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          schema: !include video.schema
          example: !include video.example
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to document this case?

Thanks!

Comment: As @farolfo says it below, there is a design issue. If anything, the above approach violates the consistency principle: why would some part of the video entity be updated with query parameters and others with an multipart/form-data entity. Just use multipart/form-data for all cases: this will make things way easier for your API users.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to send the data to change in the query params when doing a PUT request. Instead of that I'd change your second PUT for a PATCH with a Content-Type: application/json as the type of the body, and as content for that payload I'd send

```
{ title: "newTitle", description: "newDescription" }
```

With this, your API would achieve all you want to get here (as far as I get from your question).

Note that I changed this for PATCH cause in a PATCH is not mandatory for you to send the hole json with data. You might later only send a PATCH to change the description if your API implementation supports this. In a PUT request you should send the hole json.

Comment: If you go for `PATCH`, consider following RFC-6902 aka JSON Patch http://jsonpatch.com/